# Error converting .osm to .map file format for MapsForge using osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to convert .osm file downloaded from geofabrik.de to .map to use in MapsForge. I have installed osmosis and its MapsForge plugin. When I want to convert a osm file to map file I got this error/exception:

```
crosby.binary.file.FileFormatException: Unexpectedly long header 65536 bytes. Possibly corrupt file.
    at crosby.binary.file.FileBlockHead.readHead(FileBlockHead.java:50)
    at crosby.binary.file.FileBlock.process(FileBlock.java:130)
    at crosby.binary.file.BlockInputStream.process(BlockInputStream.java:34)
    at crosby.binary.osmosis.OsmosisReader.run(OsmosisReader.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The command line I use is:

```
osmosis --rb file=kyrgyzstan.osm --mapfile-writer file=kyrgyzstan.map type=hd
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not corrupted as stated by the program? Did you try another .osm file?

Comment: May be. But I just download .osm from geofabrik.de without any modification. .pbf files are ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the `--read-binary` (`--rb`) task to read what is apparently an OSM XML file (.osm extension). To read OSM XML files, use the [`--read-xml`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage#--read-xml_.28--rx.29) (`--rx`) task.